# http to https | https to http

Tags: php, drupal, .htaccess, whmcs

I have installed SSL for my website http://digitalexperts.net. The website is based on Drupal 7, for which I don't need SSL. But I also have WHMCS installed on my website in a folder named billing. The path is http://digitalexperts.net/billing

Now I want `http://digitalexperts.net/billing/*` to permanently redirect to `https://...`. I also want the rest of the website to permanently redirect to non SSL version.

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Using HTTPS throughout, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier solution would be to set the "WHMCS SSL System URL" on the General tab under General Settings. That way your site will remain as https, however your /billing folder will be https.

Comment: Should one of the above https have been an http?

Answer (score 0):

Try with htaccess:

//301 Redirect Entire Directory

RedirectMatch 301 http://digitalexperts.net/billing/(.*) https://digitalexperts.net/billing/$1

Comment: thanks for the help. can you please let me know how to redirect https://digitalexperts.net/* to http://...